# Thymeleaf, nested th:text does not show

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Nested span with price does not show, only the one with h4. How to solve this out?

```
<h4 th:text="${dish.name}">chicken fried salad <span th:text="${dish.getPrice()}">45</span></h4>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`th:text` overwrites the contents of everything inside it.  Something like this is will work for you:

```
<h4>
  <span th:text="${dish.name}">chicken fried salad</span>
  <span th:text="${dish.price}">45</span>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

First as the previous user told you, `th:text=${dish.name}` will overwrite whatever text you put inside the tag and it will place the value of `dish.name` instead.

Second - instead of `dish.getPrice()` you need to call just `dish.price` in order to view value of the `.price` attribute.